# Internal server error 500 when uploading a CSV file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

I have a very simple web app for uploading CSV files to my server. For that purpose, I'm using AJAX and JQUERY under DJANGO:

```
function Upload_Bonds(){
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formUploadBonds")); 
        var add_answer = confirm("Confirm uploading and processing of csv File?" );
        if (add_answer) {
               $.ajax({
                    url: "/cvs/DealStore/upload_bonds/", 
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: formData, 
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#message').html("<p class='text-center text-success font-weight-bold'>Success</p>");
                        window.alert("Data populated, please check the Bonds list table!");
                     },
                     error: function(data) {
                          $("#message").html("<p class='text-center text-danger font-weight-bold'>Failed</p>");
                     }
                   });
               }
      }
```

However, every time I try to use the function, I'm receiving POST 500 (Internal server error). I was able to capture the following on the browser console:

[image]

Any idea about how to handle this error? I deployed the app on another server and works fine. So maybe is something about server configuration. (I'm using Linux servers)

Thanks!

Comment: Error code 500 is very broad, server side log might help.

Comment: Sadly, the django log isn't giving any information about the error :(

Comment: Your error is coming from a function named `Upload_Bonds` not the one shown. Can you add the correct function and server logs would help a lot

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong function. I updated the question, however, they are almost the same function